# payout rate betting game

Tags: probability

There is a sequence of bets where each costs a certain amount and has a probability to win a certain amount of money depending on the cost.

so the total payout rate is:
propability * win

now in addition to the possible money win there is another probability that x free bets are triggered.
that means that the next x bets cost no money. during this streak, all probabilities are kept which means i can again trigger x free bets which extend the current streak.

how do i have to calculate this into the total payout rate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the way I view situation like this is to look at the expected value of a bet, which is the payout rate minus the cost of that bet.  With a number of free bets, the expected value increases because, assuming that the outcomes of the bets are independent, then the expected value is now $(x+1)$ times the payout rate, minus the cost of one bet.

Comment: doesnt the fact that free bets can be won during free bets lead to a Geometric series ?

Comment: I guess you are assuming that the probability of winning $k$ games is $p^k$.  But the probability of winning the $k$th game is still $p$, so it's payout is still $p$ times winnings. So the answer is no.